# Retrieve the value of textarea

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'd like to retrieve the value of textarea named "message" to display it in a FlashBag "just for test" , but it will be sent by email later. This is the form and the controller action :

**Form**

```
<form action="{{ path('immobilier_delete', {'id': immobilier.id }) }}" method="post">

<a href="{{ path('immobilier') }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" role="button">Annuler</a>
<input type="submit" value="Supprimer" class="btn btn-danger" />
<textarea name="message"></textarea>    

{{ form_rest(form) }}
</form>
```

**Action controller**

```
    public function deleteAction(Immobilier $immobilier)
{       
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()->getForm();

    $request = $this->getRequest();     

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid())
            {   
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager() ;

                // here i'd like to make the textarea in $message

                $em->remove($immobilier) ;
                $em->flush() ;


                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'message');

                return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl('immobilier'));
            }
    }

    return $this->render('AgenceImmobBundle:Immobilier:delete.html.twig',
    array(
        'immobilier' => $immobilier,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you really need to do to access a value that was posted is use $_POST['key']

So in this case your message is in: $_POST['message'].

Comment: ah thak you, so it'is a simle retrieval

Comment: Using $_POST is kinda working “around” the framework though … it provides _specific_ methods/ways of accessing form data.

Answer (score 1):

You use an empty form, remove the form and access the POST variable directly with

```
$request->request->get('message');
```

or add the message field to the form.

**Form**

```
<form action="{{ path('immobilier_delete', {'id': immobilier.id }) }}" method="post">
<a href="{{ path('immobilier') }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" role="button">Annuler</a>
<input type="submit" value="Supprimer" class="btn btn-danger" />
{{ form_widget(form) }}
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function deleteAction(Immobilier $immobilier)
{       
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('message', 'textarea')
        ->getForm();

    $request = $this->getRequest();     

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid())
            {   
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager() ;

                $em->remove($immobilier) ;
                $em->flush() ;

                $data = $form->getData();   
                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('info', $data['message']);

                return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl('immobilier'));
            }
    }

    return $this->render('AgenceImmobBundle:Immobilier:delete.html.twig',
    array(
        'immobilier' => $immobilier,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```